# Custom image size for a custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add custom image size to posts of a custom post type `articles` by following function in `functions.php`:

```
function thumb_size($id)
{
    if(get_post_type() == "articles")
    {
        add_image_size('articles-thumb', 113, 72, true);
    }
}
add_action ( 'publish_post', 'thumb_size' );
```

and trying to show it by the following code:

```
the_post_thumbnail('articles-thumb');
```

But what I see as output, doesn't have the same size as I declared, what's the problem?

Comment: This question is _unfortunately_ still relevant today. Do anyone know an interesting approach to avoid this storage and cpu unnecessary usage? Would be great having the possibility of specifying that an image adaptation is necessary only for a specific post type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the single line`add_image_size('articles-thumb', 113, 72, true);` in your functions.php file.  Remove the reset of your function and add action code.

Then display it with the line you have in your question.  `the_post_thumbnail('articles-thumb');`

You may also need to regenerate your thumbnails.  This plugin works great: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/  If your images are uploaded prior to that image size being set there won't be a thumbnail that size.  Use the plugin to regenerate a thumbnail for a single image or all images you have uploaded.  Each one regenerated will now have a thumbnail of all custom sizes.

Comment: But this will allow other post types to generate images for this specific size that he needs to be used only for "articles". No?

Comment: @RangelR.Morais Yes, technically speaking. Image sizes aren't managed by post type though, they are managed by the media library. When you upload an image WordPress creates a copy of each custom image size, then you just reference the size you need where you want to.

Answer (score 7):

I'm facing the same issue, generating a lot of image variations for any upload kind isn't a good idea.
I have a custom post type 'collection' which generates 2 different sizes that are exclusive to collection, why would I generate those sizes every upload? I could not find a solution for this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Im trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I agree - WP image handling should be improved as I can't find a way to generate 2 custom sizes ONLY for one custom post type and another 3 custom sizes ONLY for another custom post type... It generates all 5 sizes for each image!

Comment: Is this possibly by now? It would be great if we can add_image_size for specific post types only. And prevent the image sizes set by wooCommerce created when an image is uploaded to a slider, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

After uploading any image to WordPress by default it generate 3 default size of the image
Thumbnail
Medium Size
Large Size
Stop any user to use this  images sizes on your current theme use this following code in your functions.php inside theme folder Remove these using WordPress action intermediate_image_sizes_advanced then unset the thumbnail, medium and large sizes, it means there only left full image size.

```
function w3learn_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {

    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'w3learn_filter_image_sizes');`
```

Details on my [Removing default media image sizes in wordpress](http://w3-learn.com/tutorials/removing-default-media-image-sizes-in-wordpress/)